# Proof of sum of positive divisors of $n$ (probably repeated question somewhere in the stack)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

If $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$, including 1 and $n$, prove that

$$
S_\tau(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \tau(n) = \sum_{j\leq x}\left[ \frac{x}{j} \right],
$$

where $[x]$ is the largest integer not greater that $x$.

This is Proposition 1.2.2 in Jameson's *The Prime Number Theorem*. I don't understand his argument that fixing $j$ (a divisor of $n$) instead of summing over it, we only need to find $[x/j]$. A proof (if there is) using Group Theory will be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\tau(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|n}1$$
so if we let $n=dq$, we have to sum over all pairs $(d,q)$ satisfying $dq\leq x$:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\tau(n)=\sum_{dq\leq x}1
=\sum_{d\leq x}\sum_{q\leq x/d}1=\sum_{d\leq x}[x/d].$$

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$S_{\tau} (x) = \sum\limits_{1 \leq n \leq x} \tau (n) =  \sum\limits_{1 \leq n \leq x} \sum\limits_{j | n} 1 =\sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c} 1 \leq n \leq x \\ 1 \leq j \leq x \\ j | n\end{array}}  1  = \sum\limits_{1 \leq j \leq x} \sum\limits_{\begin{array}{c} n \in j \mathbb{Z} \\ 1 \leq n \leq x \end{array} } 1 =  \sum\limits_{1 \leq j \leq x}  \left[ \frac{x}{j} \right]$$
The crucial point is the exchange of the two sums. Then in the last step you use the fact that the number of multiples of $j$ which are between $1$ and $x$ is $\left[ \frac{x}{j} \right]$.

Comment: How do you get thw sum $1\leq j \leq x$?

Comment: Well since $j$ divides $n$ and $1\leq n \leq x$, you have $1 \leq j \leq x$. Note however that you can forget about this bound on $j$ is you want. In the last sum, you can write $\sum\limits_{1 \leq j \leq x}  \left[ \frac{x}{j} \right] = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{+ \infty}  \left[ \frac{x}{j} \right]$ because all the terms for $j>x$ are $0$.